Shell string escaping over SSH behaves differently on different servers
I'm trying to create a reusable script that will grep some config values for a remote WordPress site, but strings appear to be escaping differently depending on the server I'm connecting to. How can I create a command that works the same way everywhere?
For instance, on Host 1, the following outputs what I'm after, which is some_database_name\nsome_database_user:
ssh cloudwaysuser@198.246.246.246 "cat /some-path/wp-config.php | grep -E 'DB_NAME|DB_USER'"
But, on Host 2, the same command is not working because it outputs DB_NAME: command not found\nDB_USER: command not found as if it's trying to execute the string after the grep -E command:
ssh wpenginesuser@198.123.123.123 "cat /some-path/wp-config.php | grep -E 'DB_NAME|DB_USER'"
Though escaping the single quotes doesn't seem necessary in my mind, when I do escape them, I get the exact opposite behavior, so on Host 1 I get the "command not found" errors:
ssh cloudwaysuser@198.246.246.246 "cat /some-path/wp-config.php | grep -E \'DB_NAME|DB_USER\'"
and on Host 2 I get the results I'm after:
ssh wpenginesuser@198.123.123.123 "cat /some-path/wp-config.php | grep -E \'DB_NAME|DB_USER\'"
How can these two commands run differently depending on the server they're ran on, and how do I normalize them to have one command that works on both hosts?
EDIT:
As a simpler example, on Host 1, ssh cloudwaysuser@198.246.246.246 "echo \"'TEST'\"" outputs 'TEST' as I'd expect, but for Host 2 ssh wpenginesuser@198.123.123.123 "echo \"'TEST'\"" outputs TEST without the single quotes. Why might that be the case and how do I make these behave the same?
Edit 2:
Note though my script is much more complex than just what's shown above, which is minimal reproduction of the issue. In my script I have multiple .json files, each with all details for connecting to a different server, and this script reads that into a bunch of variables that backup and launch the files and database (with custom rsync excludes, database URL find-and-replacements, etc.). So, rewriting the above script to avoid expansion only solves this one use case, and then there are many other commands in my script that still fail due to the quotes being stripped on WP Engine's servers.

Not related to your problem, but always prefer grep -E 'pattern' file or grep -E 'pattern' <file to cat file | grep -E pattern. It's not as important for grep as other common commands, but a FIFO can only be read once, front-to-back, whereas a real file handle can be read out-of-order, can have its size checked without needing to consume all its content, and otherwise allows a lot of optimizations that let other common tools (tail, sort, wc -c, and others) operate much more efficiently when they have a real handle and not a pipe.

As for the immediate problem -- strings you passed are parsed by the remote shell; your local client-side system doesn't have much control over which shell that is. One thing you can do is ssh hostname 'bash -c' <<'EOF' and then feed the code to run on stdin -- that way you know it'll be processed by bash, at least if what you're getting is a "real" shell and bash is itself available.

I'd investigate Host 2 (and the account you're logging into on it) to find out why it's doing this. What shell is it using for ssh logins? Does it have a ~/.ssh/rc and/or /etc/ssh/sshrc script? If you're authenticating against a public key, does the relevant entry in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys have a command option (i.e. a script to run to pre-process the command sent over ssh)? Alternately, if the file isn't too big and/or the connection too slow, you could run grep locally: ssh wpenginesuser@198.123.123.123 "cat /some-path/wp-config.php" | grep -E 'DB_NAME|DB_USER'

What if you try to run sed directly from ssh: ssh cloudwaysuser@198.246.246.246 sed -ne \''/DB_NAME\|DB_USER/{ s/.*, *\o47\(.*\)\o47.*/\1/;H;};${x;s/^\n//;s|\n|/|g;p}'\' /some-path/wp-config.php Note path file isn't quoted. not needed if your path don't contain spaces.

Charles Duffy is (as always!) correct, but I wanted to add an example for his comment in case it wasn't clear. Instead of:
ssh cloudwaysuser@198.246.246.246 "cat /some-path/wp-config.php | grep -E 'DB_NAME|DB_USER'"

You can run this:
ssh cloudwaysuser@198.246.246.246 bash -s <<'EOF'
cat /some-path/wp-config.php | grep -E 'DB_NAME|DB_USER'
EOF

(Using <<'EOF' instead of <<EOF suppresses variable expansion in the local shell, which is important for avoiding confusion if your shell uses variables.)
By passing the shell script on stdin rather than on the command line, we avoid a number of problems around quoting and tokenization that can otherwise complicate a seemingly simple script.

I'd pass bash -s (on the ssh command line) as an explicit command just in case the remote default is something bizarre.

Avoid useless use of cat!  grep -E 'DB_NAME|DB_USER' </some-path/wp-config.php!

Then even: ssh user@target bash -s <<<"grep -E 'DB_NAME|DB_USER' </some-path/wp-config.php"

Unfortunately, that last example will break unexpectedly off your script includes variable references. Using single quotes would help, but it is still problematic if your script itself requires multiple levels of quoting. Using a heredoc as shown in the answer avoids these problems.

This solved my issue for some purposes, but not others, like the issue I'm now having piping a file to the server. If I could get both servers to treat strings the same, I wouldn't be running into the pipe+heredoc stdin issues mentioned in that thread and my problem would be solved.
